# Designing a high performing hotel room booking system

Tags: database-design, architecture, nosql, scalability, database-performance

I am facing a situation of designing a booking system of a hotel website that may handle thousand and thousands of hotel rooms, and their availability. Something like the Expedia website.

This availability would need to be stored locally, and I would need to query these hotel rooms for availability.

So far I have arrived in the following structure:

- A division of room_type, which would be a combination of its characteristics, such as if it has a view, or maximum people in the room, e.g.: with view/3 people would be a type alone, and other types would be: with view/4 people, no view 2 people, with view/4 people, etc.\
- Each room would be assigned to a room_type for presentation purposes in the frontend. E.g.: I wouldn't show the individual room record, (e.g.: room 201), but I would show that I have room available of that type.
- So I would have a room "table" and a room_type "table" and each room would have a type.
- Then there is a matrix of rooms (rows) and dates (columns) from today and up to 6 months in the future.

The matrix would look like the following:
[image: Availability matrix]

Where 1 means that room is available on that date, and 0 means it is booked. So for me to detect if a room_type is available in a date range, I have to:

1. For each room of this type;
2. Scan all columns between the required dates;
3. If there is a room in which no 0s were found in that row, it means it is available, so it means that this room_type can be shown as available for that date range.

In the above table, suppose the date range was 10/10/2017 to 10/14/2017 (US format), the only available room would be room 101 at hotel C.

I can then book a Customer to that room, so the customer won't need to change rooms during his/hers stay.

**My questions are:**

- Is there any storage that can hold a big Matrix like that in memory? (MySQL, Redis, PostgreSQL, Cassandra, MongoDB, etc)
- If a RDBMS is what I should use, what kind? Should I use a traditional RDBMS? Or would this "matrix-like structure" fit better another flavour of newer NoSQL database.
- Is this "matrix-like structure" how these huge highly visited websites structure their data? (E.g.: Expedia, Booking.com, Trivago, etc) Or is there a better method that is faster to query for date ranges?

I am worried about not picking the correct structure now, and stumble into performance problems later in the future when the website is under high demand and with an even higher volume of rooms.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks for the question. It is one of the complex problems that I know, considering the variety of use-cases that will come on top of just the basic hotel availability. Some examples: how do you do geo-searches, how to support multiple check-ins in the same day for the same room, how to keep the data highly consistent with the world-view (the up-to-date price and availability), how do you rank hotels based on their price, how to add more attributes like custom benefits (smoke-free, 24-hour checkin, kitchen included, etc.), how to handle different cancellation policy, etc.

You get the point, I believe.

The best designs I have encountered use column or schema-less stores (like cassandra, mongo), along with a RDBMS.

NoSQL stores give flexibility to keep adding more attributes and also to search across multiple dimensions like city, nearby search, etc.

RDBMS can store rarely changing data like different room types, hotel description, etc.

For example, for the simple use-case above, I would store all the different room types, hotel to room mappings in a RDBMS. But the hotel price and availability would go to a NoSQL store. I would have room prices and availability stored in a NoSQL store with search attributes like check-in/check-out date, number of people, number of rooms as the keys to this table. I would have a cron job running periodically to populate all the different search permutations for all the rooms available (by cross lookups on another booking table) and update the NoSQL store. This way the read-path is faster (this is very similar to fan-out on write approach that many social media websites design their architecture. Optimise the read path and propagate updates on the write-path, fully aware that read-data can be a little stale). In our case, the price and availability might be stale for the time period between the cron job runs, but this can be easily offset by making another check with a consistent store (say a booking table), just before the time of booking. If there are differences, you can start the workflow again.

Note: the above is a highly subjective opinion and based on the assumption that prices and availability change infrequently. You could use a combination of streaming systems like kafka to make the updates faster

Comment: Why would you make the assumption that hotel availability changes infrequently? In a booking system wouldn't that be the most frequently changing thing? Unless virtually no one is using the system and booking reservations. Also very confused as to why you would choose to store reservation information in db that is not ACID compliant.